# Safari HTML 5 video not playing

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, safari

I'm currently trying to incorporate a full screen video BG in my home slider (via Revolution SLider, a WP plugin which supports HTML5 video).

The video loads fine in FF and Chrome, but I get nothing but the loading .gif and a black screen in Safari - I've got both .mp4 and .ogv available and linked, so I know the correct format is there.

Any ideas/solutions would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

> Use the specific video format safari uses.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Multi-Scheme Video Player</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <video controls autoplay >
             <source src="http://HttpLiveStream.m3u8">
             <source src="rtsp://LegacyStream.3gp">
             <source src="http://ProgressiveDownload.m4v">
      </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Here you will find things properly about video support by particular browser [**CLICK HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)